# How to draw image on Grid in silverlight?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, image, grid, silverlight-3.0

I am making an application using Silverlight 3.0. In that application i am drawing a waveform on grid.Now i want to show a image at the bottom of waveform  repeatedly. I am not getting what i have to do now? Please help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight doesn't support this out of the box. However you can create your own image control that supports tiling or use something like [ExImage](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54147/ExImage-A-Silverlight-control-very-similar-to-the). Other option is to make your Silverlight host transparent and use CSS for the background.